# CORBA IDL: How can we declare something like this in java rmi in corba

Tags: java, corba

I have a method which returns a hashmap. How can we implement this ?

public HashMap displayBookList() throws RemoteException;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to return a bidimensional array and use [0] as key and [1] as value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ,you could define the corba IDL files as below:

```
struct KeyVal {
    string key;
    string value;
};

typedef sequence<KeyVal> KeyValSeq;

KeyValSeq displayBookList();
```